# PHP Script stopping abruptly (imagecopyresampled)

Tags: php, image, memory

I have this script below that stops without an error after a certain amount of iterations. When the images it is using are ~4MB, the script stops after about 10 iterations. When the images are around 1MB, the script stops after ~30 iterations. When the images are smaller, the script can go for 500 iterations. It doesn't seem to be a timeout, as it happens at a different time count each time.

When I test this on my own machine using xxamp, there are no errors, and the script finishes perfectly.

I am guessing this is some type of memory problem? I am completely inexperienced and clueless when it comes to memory.

EDIT:
I put an echo before the  imagecopyresampled function and after. The script seems to stop on this function.

Here is my loop that goes through each file in the directory:

```
while (false !== ($filer = readdir($handle))) {
      if (is_file($srcDir . '/' . $filer)) {

          set_time_limit(20);
          $counter++;
          $total = $x;
          $percent = intval($counter/$total * 100)."%";

        // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
          echo '<script language="javascript">
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#333;\">&nbsp;</div>";
            document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$counter.' images processed.";
            </script>';

        //location/filename variable
        $filename = $srcDir . '/' . $filer;

        // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
        echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

        // Send output to browser immediately
        flush();


        //get the extension of the image
        $path_parts = pathinfo("$filename");
        $ext = strtolower ($path_parts['extension']);

        $width = 100;
        $height = 100;

        // Get new dimensions
        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);
        $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

        if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
        $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
        } else {
        $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
        }

        // Resample
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

    // Output the small image
    imagejpeg($image_p, "$destDir/$filer", 100);

    //Move the big image
     rename($srcDir . '/' . $filer, $destDirbig . '/' . $filer);
    echo $counter;

      }

    }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm not sure that `false !== ($file = readdir($handle))` is the correct syntax. `!=` is the standard for 'not equal'. If you are trying to text if it is 'exactly not equal', I would guess you want `!(($file = readdir($handle)) === false)`

Answer (score 0):

Raise the value of `set_time_limit(20);` to a higher timeout value...

Providing the error message may give more insight.

Also, after using `imagejpeg`, use `imagedestroy($image_p)` to free up memory.

Comment: There is no error message, I have tried both of those, still get the abrupt ending to my loop.

Comment: Well, since you're not checking what kind of file you're trying to process, there's a high probability you're hitting a non JPEG file... Try enabling `error_reporting` to see.

Comment: Error reporting is enabled, I have put non JPEGs in there and I do get an error.

Comment: Ok then... that's your problem... You should, probably right after `is_file`, check if it's an image.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I have put non jpegs in there to test if there is an error. Currently there is no error because there are only jpegs in there. If I keep running the script, eventually all the images get converted.

Comment: I'm confused then, what's the problem if they eventually finish processing? Did you raise the `set_time_limit` value (or set it to 0)?

Comment: I am just wondering why the script stops. If there are 900 images, I may have to start the script 30+ times to get all the images to convert. Yep, I have changed set_time_limit.

Comment: You are still probably hitting hidden files that are not JPEG's. There's also no error handling here either.. what if you hit a bad JPEG, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding some of your own error logging.

```
$filename = $srcDir . '/' . $filer;

echo "Trying {$filename}";

if (is_file($filename)) {

    //do the processing

} else {
    echo "{$filename} was not a file";
}
```

Then you will at least see which files it tries and when it stops working. See if there is a pattern?

Comment: The thing is that the all the images get processed if I keep manually restarting the script. It isn't stopping on a particular image, its stopping after X number of images. (X changes based on image size)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, the solution is to temporarily increase the memory limit script:

```
ini_set ("memory_limit", "100M");
```